# Updated Macbook to Ventura - now getting 'command not found: Flutter'

Tags: python, flutter, macos, dart, macos-ventura

Oddly enough I'm able to run my flutter applications, but I'd like to upgrade. However since I've updated to MacOS Ventura Flutter can't be found anymore...

output of `echo $PATH`:

```
/Users/me/bin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/System/Cryptexes/App/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/flutter/bin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands
```

What the top of my `.zshrc` file looks like:

```
# If you come from bash you might have to change your $PATH.
export PATH=$HOME/bin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH

# Path to your oh-my-zsh installation.
export ZSH="$HOME/.oh-my-zsh"
```

Any help and info is greatly appreciated

> P.S dart and python also cannot be found. But they're not in my path so guess that makes sense

Comment: What is the path to your flutter installation? Is it inside $PATH? How did you install flutter? Via brew or some other way?

Comment: @jraufeisen downloaded physical package about a year and a half ago via https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install/macos and saved into my Developer Folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you normally start flutter by typing:

```
Flutter
```

you can search in `/usr` and `/opt` for a file (rather than a directory) that is executable (i.e. a program) and called `Flutter` like this:

```
find /usr /opt -name "Flutter" -type f -perm +111
```

Then, if/when you find it, add the name of the directory that contains `Flutter` to your `PATH`. So if it finds:

```
/opt/homebrew/bin/Flutter
```

you would do:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/homebrew/bin
```

If you don't find it in `/usr` or `/opt`, you will need to perform a more time-consuming search across the whole filesystem and also suppress error messages:

```
find / -name "Flutter" -type f -perm +111 2> /dev/null
```

Comment: It definitely wasn't via brew that I downloaded Flutter. But this answer and comment reminded me where it was actually saved a long time ago, which downloaded from Flutters website and put in the Developer folder. Thanks all